# Display List with GLTesselated objects? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Is it possible to create a display list for Tesselated objects? If so would it be more efficient?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes -- after tessellation you just have a bunch of triangles, which you can put in a display list about like anything else. Efficiency will depend; on nVidia display lists work quite well, but on ATI a display list is little different from multiple calls to glVertex.

If you want to assure efficiency across both, consider using a vertex buffer object instead of a display list. This is also supported by the newer versions of OpenGL (display lists are deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Efficient but deprecated.